# How to close Fancybox from a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, fancybox

I know there is a lot of topics with this questions, but I don't found the answer to my particular question ...

Refer to the FAQ, we had to use one of these to close the fancybox.

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

or

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

But this doesn't work in my case.

I use an AJAX type of fancybox, see below :

```
  $('.fancybox2').fancybox({

            type: 'ajax',
            title: 'Admin',
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 400,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'none',
        });
```

So after the click on a button, it shows another page in the fancybox.
In this page there is a button with the following code :

```
<input type=button onclick="$.fancybox.close();" value="Save" style="margin-top:30px;" class=button>
```

Comment: Can you try **$.fn.fancybox.close()**  on click event.?

Comment: I tried it too but the console returns me :
TypeError: $.fn.fancybox.close is not a function

Comment: $.fn.fancybox.close() doesn't work for version 2.x, in fact, it raises an error. If you're using version 2.x, try $.fancybox.close(true) instead.

Comment: Yes I'm using version 2.1.5, I tried $.fancybox.close(true); and same result ... I tried to use this with the xAqweRx's method and same result again ><

Answer (score 3):

Your `onclick="$.fancybox.close();"` doesn't see your main fancybox object.
Try to do something like this

```
<input type="button" value="Save" style="margin-top:30px;" class="button closeFancybox">
```

And in your main document

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.closeFancybox',function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
    })
})
```

---

**Update**

Please try to simulate similar behaviour on https://jsfiddle.net
I've tried example that you've wrote and it worked.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Nothing happend.
I added a console.log('test') before $.fancybox.close(); and it returns the log, so he entered in the function

Comment: No I can't, it's not online. It's on a local website :/

Comment: Do you use jQuery.noConflict mode?  
Try to off other JS libraries. Clean instance of fancybox works good.

Comment: I tried the jQuery.noConflict mode and it gives the same result.
I tried to off other JS libraries and it doesn't works too.

Comment: @EuroplisLogistique please try to simuleate this on https://jsfiddle.net/ and tell whether it works there or not. Because I've tried to do all the same way and it worked.